# How to Unit test an AsyncTask which await another Async task?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, async-await, microsoft-fakes, shim

```
public async Task<ResModel> GetDetails()
{
    ResModel resp = new ResModel();
    resp = await MobController.GetAllDeatails();
    return resp;
}
```

In the `await` this calls for an async task method named `GetAllDeatails` and returns an object `ResModel`.

How to properly create an unit test for this?

The unit test I've created is right below:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetFromGetDetails()
{
    var controller = new SevicesController();
    ResModel resp = new ResModel();

    using(ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ProjectAPI.Fakes.ShimMobController.GetAllDeatails = () => {
            resp.MessageType = "Get"
            resp.Message ="contdetail";

            return resp;
        };

        returnValueOfAsyncTask = await controller.GetDetails();

        Assert.IsNotNull(returnValueOfAsyncTask);
    }

}
```

This gives errors in the `ShimContext` creation because the return type must be async in `GetAllDeatails` but here it only returns the object.

Following is the main error I'm getting:

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel'` to
>   `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel>'`
>   Un‌​itTestProjectAPI

Comment: Dear @BartoszKP I have edited the question. and narrow it down as you suggested. the problem must be with the fake method creating as **ProjectAPI.Fakes.ShimMobController.GetAllDeatails**. because this must return an Async object. but here it only returns an object.

Comment: Thanks, this is much better. It is best however, to paste the error message in the post, so it's completely clear what error you're talking about :)

Comment: Thanks @BartoszKP

**Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel>' UnitTestProjectAPI**

Is the main error I'm getting. problem must be the difference between the return type that I'm creating as a fake and the given AsyncTask method. any Idea....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly states that it cannot convert the `ResModel` to a `Task<ResModel>` which is the return type of the method being shimmed.

In the shim you are returning the model when the method is suppose to be returning a Task. Use `Task.FromResult` in order to wrap the model in a Task so that it can be return and awaited.

In the exercising of the method under test you stated that the variable used to hold the result of the await was a `Task<ResModel>`. That should be changed because when you `await` a Task that returns a result it will just return the result not the task. So that result variable needs to be changed to from `Task<ResModel>` to `ResModel`.

Here is the update unit test based on above changes.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetFromGetDetails() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = new SevicesController();
    var expected = new ResModel();

    using(ShimsContext.Create()) {

        ProjectAPI.Fakes.ShimMobController.GetAllDeatails = () => {
            expected.MessageType = "Get"
            expected.Message ="contdetail";

            return Task.FromResult(expected); 
        };

        //Act
        var actual = await controller.GetDetails();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Nkosi Thanks for your quick answer here. I tried that too. but at the line of **returnValueOfAsyncTask = await controller.GetDetails() as Response;**  line gives the same above error. any suggestions?

but this narrowed down me to a one line thank you.

Comment: @TharushaShehan What type is `returnValueOfAsyncTask` and what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Dear @Nkosi The error is the same error as above.
**Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type  'ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ProjectAPI.Models.ResModel>' Un‌​itTestProjectAPI**
Now it only gives in the line I mentioned at the comment. As for **returnValueOfAsyncTask ** is the   variable that I'm Asserting as the unit test and it is a **Task<ResModel>**

Comment: Well that is the problem. when you use await it returns the `ResModel` not a Task

Comment: Dear @Nkosi thank again. wow this did the trick and build the code thank you very much. but this gives a warning saying **This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound on a background thread.** can you suggest a solution for this too.

Comment: @TharushaShehan to where is that warning referring.

Comment: Dear @Nkosi can you update the answer for some extend(including an assert if you interested). In order for me to make this as the answer. thank again. this will help others as well.

Comment: @TharushaShehan I did not understand your last comment. clarify

Comment: Dear @Nkosi the error is gone now. as for the warning that was given I changed the return type to void in the Test method. now all are clear. thank you very much for your help. You saved me from lot of trouble.

Another favor please. can you update the answer a bit with the mistakes I have made above. and mentioning them more. so I can make it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Method return type
 to

(public async Task
<
ResModel> GetFromGetDetails()

Comment: That is the test method. there is no need to change that.

Comment: Dear @Shoba thanks for your answer. but I cannot change the source code. It is connected with many other functionalities. so I can not change it for testing purposes only.